# Case insensitive string::find

Tags: c++

Is there exist a case-insensitive `find()` method for `std::string`?

Comment: Depends on the meaning of "case insensitive." Do you have only ASCII letters, or do you need full Unicode collation?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could upper-case both strings and use the regular find. (Note: this approach may not be correct if you have Unicode string.)

In Boost there's also `ifind_first` for case-insensitive search. (note that it returns a range instead of a `size_t`).

```
#include <string>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/find.hpp>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cctype>

std::string upperCase(std::string input) {
  for (std::string::iterator it = input.begin(); it != input.end(); ++ it)
    *it = toupper(*it);
  return input;
}

int main () {
  std::string foo = "1 FoO 2 foo";
  std::string target = "foo";

  printf("string.find: %zu\n", foo.find(target));

  printf("string.find w/ upperCase: %zu\n", upperCase(foo).find(upperCase(target)));

  printf("ifind_first: %zu\n", boost::algorithm::ifind_first(foo, target).begin() - foo.begin());

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I just gave ifind_first a test drive, and it was slower than converting the 2 strings to lower casee (using boost) and using std::string::find.

Comment: But it will not work for Unicode in the general case. "ß" and "SS" should compare equal, but Boost String Algorithms doesn't handle this.

Comment: @dalle: In that case you should use Unicode libraries like `libicu` (you probably need a locale to be aware of the Turkish İ in these cases too).

Comment: Yes, probably. Too bad the C++ standard library is unaware of Unicode.

Answer (score 5):

this is what I would have suggested, (the same as @programmersbook)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

bool lower_test (char l, char r) {
  return (std::tolower(l) == std::tolower(r));
}

int main()
{
  std::string text("foo BaR");
  std::string search("bar");

  std::string::iterator fpos = std::search(text.begin(), text.end(), search.begin(), search.end(), lower_test);
  if (fpos != text.end())
    std::cout << "found at: " << std::distance(text.begin(), fpos) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Before doing anything fancy, have a look at

http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/029.htm

and see if using a custom character traits class is not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0; i<yourString.length() 
    && tolower(yourString[i])!=yourLoweredChar; i++)
{
    return i;
}
return -1;
```

If -1 is returned then your target char is not there

else gives the first occurrance of the char

Answer (score 0):

The Most Efficient Way

> > Performance is guaranteed to be linear, with an initialization cost of 2 * NEEDLE_LEN comparisons. (glic)

```cpp
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main(void) {

    std::string s1{"abc de fGH"};
    std::string s2{"DE"};

    auto pos = strcasestr(s1.c_str(), s2.c_str());

    if(pos != nullptr)
        std::cout << pos - s1.c_str() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `strcasestr` is not part of standard C++.

Comment: @Evg.For sure.But you could use `StrStrIA` on windows with `#pragma comment(lib,"shlwapi.lib") `